# Is there any possibility of semi-automated text execution in selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, python

Can one semi-automate the test execution, say there are certain things that we can`t do using selenium like captcha issue, so is it possible to start the script, perform some task manually and automate others, in the same session or any other approach that solves the same problem.

**Example scenario**

1. Login. (Selenium)
2. Captcha. (Take control and solve it yourself, in the same session)
3. Perform some task. (Selenium)
4. Logout. (Selenium)

Comment: you can throw a message box and wait for user input to continue the execution, meantime you can complete the semi-manual tasks

Comment: I think its not duplicate one. Question is different from the mapped similar question. Here the initial process(login) is not from the user its from selenium only in intermediate steps user action(manual process) takes place how could this will be solved if browser is opened manually .

Comment: @MohamedSulaimaanSheriff Read all the answers, one answer suggests adding breakpoints, one suggest throwing pop message box and waiting for user input  before continuing, these are the approaches for semi-automated tests

Comment: @PDHide But i have mentioned only the mapped similar question which is not related to this to mark as duplicate. May be any other questions can make this duplicate so it will be good to map that particular question so that it helps the questionnaire

Comment: Ho thanks for pointing it out, I edited the title. Initially doing something and then adding automation , and initially starting automation and halting for few mins to accommodate manual intervention , are just two approaches of semi-automated. I edited the title to make it more generic .

Answer (score 0):

After login step use `Webdriver Wait` to wait until some of the element of landing page(after login) is displayed.

For example, if you have an account username UI element in the landing page you can make `WebDriver` to wait until the element is displayed

```
WebDriverWait wait==new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
```

So in this meantime, you can perform the action where driver execution will wait for 10 seconds.

`element` should be a WebDriver element from the landing page which is displayed after login